# Rails error: unable to open database file (SQLite3::CantOpenException)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite

I created a Rails web app, pushed to github, pulled down onto a Raspberry Pi.
Ran "rake db:create RAILS_ENV=production" along with db:migrate.

When I run the WEBrick server (in production environment), it works perfectly.  But when I try to run it through Apache, I get the Phusion Passenger error screen:

```
Web application could not be started
unable to open database file (SQLite3::CantOpenException)
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:26:in `initialize'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:26:in `new'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:26:in `sqlite3_connection'
```

I already changed the owner and group of the production.sqlite3 file to be "www-data", and chmod 666.  Also edited the database.yml file so it contains the full path to the database files rather than the relative path.

Not sure what else to try.

Comment: Maybe u have not migrated, so is the error. do: rails db:migrate

Answer (score -1):

It's because nginx create www-data user, and this user don't have a previlegues to read sqlite3 file and your app...

You need to run this command:

1. `sudo chown -R www-data:www-data rails_project/`
2. `sudo chmod -R 777 rails_project/`